# Find the length of DC to the nearest first decimal place.

Tags: area

In the trapezium  ABCD shown in the figure, AB = (x + 3) cm, DC = (2x − 3) cm  and  BE = EC. If the area of the trapezium is $15 cm^2$, find the length of DC to the nearest first decimal place.  (Take$ \sqrt{19}$ = 4.36)

[image]

Any Ideas on how to begin?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To begin, note that $EC=BE=x-6$  Now use the area you are given to find $x$.

Comment: EC=BE=x−6 How did this happen?

Comment: Compare $DC$ to $AB$ and note that $DE=AB$

Comment: $15$=$\frac{3 (x-6) x}{2}$ Correct

Comment: Yes.  I believe it would be clearer to write $15=(x+3)(x-6)+\frac 12(x-6)^2$, which shows you added the rectangle and triangle, but your equation is equivalent.  Now when you solve for $x$ you will see where $\sqrt{19}$ comes in.

Comment: DC=7.36, Correct? :)

Comment: No, you dropped a factor $2$ on the $\sqrt{19}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Height $h = BE = EC = (2x-3) -(x+3) = ..$, and use the area formula for a trapezoid: $15 = \dfrac{(b+B)h}{2} = \dfrac{((x+3)+(2x-3))h}{2}$ to solve for $x$.

Comment: $15 = \dfrac{(b+B)h}{2} = \dfrac{((x+3)+(2x-3))h}{2}$=
$\dfrac{(3x)h}{2}$=
$\dfrac{3hxh}{2}$=
$\dfrac{4hx}{2}$ = $2hx $ Correct?

Comment: You need to redo it because I spotted a mistake in your comment...

Comment: can please show me where?